# What is the official name of this "shorting bar 5-position" header?

Tags: identification, components, busbar

I have purchased this item locally in the past and basically its 5 wires aligned in parallel, and makes my circuitry much easier (eliminates the needs to manually connect 5 individual wires side-by-side). They are however running out of stock and I'd like to buy more. In fact, If such a thing exists, I'd like to buy this project where there are 8 connectors on each side instead of 5.

The closest thing I could come up with is searching for a DIP resistor, but what ebay returned to me is a 22 ohm DIP resistor, however, I'd like something that has zero resistance. I searched for 0 ohm DIP resistor and found nothing.

Is there another name I can use as a query for this part?

[image: Item]

Comment: how many thousand pcs do you need and when?  2.5mm? or 2?

Comment: I generally use 0.1" pitch male pins and solder a tinned wire on the top. Always readily available. It can be sealed it with epoxy as well. 
Of course, if you need large quantity, this approach is not the best.

Comment: One of the problems of buying surplus stock is that it may not be available indefinitely. I can't quite see what that  part looks like. Would a programmable shunt such as 1825190-7 TE work?

Comment: Google for (DIL or SIL = dual or single in line) header or jumper. Carefully check the pitch. Do an image search and find the one that matches best to yours. Then look what they are called, rinse & repeat. A DIP switch may be an option too.

Comment: You could make one from a header and some solder or lead cutoffs.